# Automorphisms on upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation, mobius-function

I am supposed to prove that: \begin{align} Aut(\mathbb{H})= \left\{ T:\mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{H}, T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d} \vert a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}; ad-bc>0 \right\} \end{align}.
where $\mathbb{H}$ denotes the upper half plane of the complex plane. I was able to show "$\supseteq$", but a have a hard time for the other direction. My idea was to look at a function $g:= C\circ f\circ C^{-1}$ where $C$ is the Cayley function and $f \in Aut(\mathbb{D})$ and $\mathbb{D}$ as the unit disc and then use maybe schwarzes Lemma. the problem is, I didn't even get $g(0)=0$, so I couldn't apply schwarz Lemma and even then I'm not sure if this would even work. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's something off in your statement to be proved. The upper half-plane is not a set of transformations on it. Did you mean $Aut( \mathbb H)$ on the left?

Comment: I think your strategy is sound. You might want to start by checking that the action of this subgroup of automorphisms is transitive on the upper half plane, and then composing the Cayley transform with some other map coming from this.

Comment: @coffeemath Yeah, thanks. I edited the original question.

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon I tried working on this using Cayley function an an automorphism on $\mathbb{D}$, which maps $z_*$ to $0$. Then I could look at the function $f(z)=(T_{z_*}\circ C\circ g \circ C^{-1}$ and $g \in \mathbb{H}$. Then I can use Schwarz Lemma, but from here on I got stuck - I wouldn’t get the correct form in the end.

Comment: @MilesDefis you really need to use a Möbius transform on the plane, composing with a "generic" automorphism of the plane will not work, if you can't assume that this automorphism has the desired shape. Let me know if you'd like me to post a proper answer!

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon please do so. Other than this I couldn’t figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is my try; let me preface this by saying there there are probably many standard proofs of this fact in textbooks, and I am not sure that what I write below is 100% correct, so if anyone wants to improve/correct something, feel free to do so!

Anyway, let $f:\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{H}$ be a biholomorphism, and denote by $\zeta$ the complex number $f(i)$. For the moment, assume there is a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c &d\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ with positive determinant, such that the induced Möbius transformation
$$\varphi:z\mapsto\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
sends $\zeta$ to $i$, so that $\varphi\circ f$ is a biholomorphism of $\mathbb{H}$ such that $\varphi\circ f(i)=i$. With this in place, we can use your idea: consider the Cayley transform $C:\mathbb{CP}^1\to\mathbb{CP}^1$, defined on $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{CP}^1\setminus\{\infty\}$ by $$C(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i},$$ and consider the composition $\psi=C\circ\varphi\circ f\circ C^{-1}$. This is a biholomorphism of the disk, since $C$ maps the upper-half plane to the disk, and as $\varphi\circ f(i)=i$, we deduce that $\psi(0)=0$. Also, notice that $\lvert\psi'(0)\rvert\not=0$, as the maps $C$, $\varphi$, and $f$ are all holomorphic and injective. By the Schwarz Lemma (or the Riemann mapping Theorem) then we deduce that there is some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, $\alpha\not=0$, such that $\psi(z)=\alpha z$. Notice also that $\lvert\alpha\rvert=1$, as $\psi$ preserves $\partial\mathbb{D}$.

Then, for the original biholomorphism $f$ we get $$f(z)=\varphi^{-1}\left(C^{-1}(\alpha\,C(z))\right).$$ Now, we just need to show that $C^{-1}(\alpha\,C(z))$ is a Möbius transform, as $\varphi$ is a Möbius transformation and the Möbius transformations form a group (exercise!)

So, let's compute:
\begin{equation}
C^{-1}(\alpha\,C(z))=\frac{\alpha\,C(z)+1}{i \alpha\,C(z)-i}=\frac{1}{i}\frac{\alpha\frac{z-i}{z+i}+1}{\alpha\frac{z-i}{z+i}-1}=\frac{1}{i}\frac{\alpha(z-i)+z+i}{\alpha(z-i)-(z+i)}=\frac{z(\alpha+1)+i(1-\alpha)}{z\,i(\alpha-1)+(1+\alpha)}.
\end{equation}
This is not quite a Möbius transform, as the coefficients are not real. However, we can rewrite it (if $\alpha\not=-1$, but in that case we already have a Möbius transform) as
$$\frac{z(\alpha+1)+i(1-\alpha)}{z\,i(\alpha-1)+(1+\alpha)}=\frac{z\lvert 1+\alpha\rvert^2+i(1-\alpha)(\bar{\alpha}+1)}{z\,i(\alpha-1)(\bar{\alpha}+1)+\lvert 1+\alpha\rvert^2},$$
that is, since $\alpha$ has norm $1$,
\begin{equation}
C^{-1}(\alpha\,C(z))=\frac{z\lvert 1+\alpha\rvert^2+2\,\Im(\alpha)}{-2\,\Im(\alpha)\,z+\lvert 1+\alpha\rvert^2}
\end{equation}
is the Möbius transformation associated to the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}\lvert 1+\alpha\rvert^2 & 2\Im(\alpha) \\ -2\Im(\alpha) & \lvert 1+\alpha\rvert^2\end{pmatrix}.$$

So, it remains to prove the claim laid out at the beginning, that for each $\zeta$ there is a Möbius transformation sending $\zeta$ to $i$. This can be obtained as the composition of two different transformations: first find a matrix whose associated map $\varphi_0$ translates $\zeta$ to the imaginary axis $i\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, then compose it with a second Möbius transformation $\varphi_1$ that rescales the imaginary axis. I think it would be a good exercise for you to try to find these two transformations, let me know if you need help for that!